# How to use chance.js directly into html in a node application? (Roots)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using roots (a nodeJS based tool, https://www.npmjs.com/package/roots) to generate static html. I combined it with chance.js in order to randomly generate fake data:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chance

However, I have a hard time using chance directly into html:

```
a=chance.address()
```

this code results in error:

```
Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

I know that chance.js is running alright because I can console.log(chance.address()) in the browser's console.

How should I make this work?

Comment: Please add more code on what you tried to do.

Comment: The code that I tried to implement is to print out a random address:
a=chance.address()

Comment: I mean, you just don't have enough code for anyone to determine what the problem is. My assumption is that you're missing `var chance = require('chance');`.

Comment: adding var chance = require('chance'); to script.js or into the document itself both results in errors. Where should I put it?

    error: require is not defined